# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError without strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have got the below hash:

```
hash = {
  "role"=>"#", 
  "city"=>"#", 
  "listing_attributes"=>
    {
      "desks_attributes"=>
        {
          "0"=>{"quantity_available"=>"#"}
        }
    },
  "username"=>"#", 
  "email"=>"#", 
  "fullname"=>"#", 
  "password"=>"#", 
  "password_confirmation"=>"#", 
  "terms"=>"#"
}
```

And I am trying to build a User model object:

```
User.new(
  :username => hash[:username],
  :fullname => hash[:fullname],
  :first_name => hash[:first_name],
  :last_name => hash[:last_name],
  :email => hash[:email],
  :password => hash[:password],
  :password_confirmation => hash[:password_confirmation],
  :role => hash[:role],
  :city => hash[:city],
  :terms => hash[:terms],
  :listing_attributes => hash[:listing_attributes]
)
```

And it seems to return the following ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError, I understand that this error can raise it's head when using strong parameters but I can't workout how to get round it when not using strong parameters? Or is there a way that I am able to incorporate strong parameters into this code?

For the record I have got the following models:

```
class Desk < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing
  has_one :user, through:  :listing
end

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :desks, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :desks
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :listing, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :desks, :through => :listing
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :listing
end
```

And I have following set up for my strong parameters:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:username, :fullname, :first_name, :last_name,:email, :password, :password_confirmation,:password_digest, :role, :city, :terms,listing_attributes: [:company_name, :address, :post_code, :user_id, :city, :latitude, :longitude, desks_attributes: [:quantity_available]])
```

Comment: If you look in the development.log, you normally see, which params are not whitelisted. Would it give any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Did you permit all parameters in your controller? 

Example:

```
private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :salt, :encrypted_password)
  end
```

Comment: I have updated the question to include the strong parameters I have got set up